# How can I fix height on MaterialUI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, height

How can I fix this white line?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi9FA.jpg)
If I make height:100% it looks so:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40UPi.jpg)

Comment: Please add your code as code text and not link to images

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main page component which contains all the components of your page like App.js
Add a Box element and add some styling in it.

```
<Box sx={{height:'100vh', background:'your_background'}}>
   Your components
</Box>
```